# Using PowerShell Where-Object not working with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to get directories that contain "COO", but after adding the `Where-Object` nothing is returned, the script is looping through each of the folders but nothing makes it to the file when the `Where-Object` is in place.

This works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory | select Fullname | Export-csv c:users\shay\desktop\test.csv
```

This doesn't:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory | Select Fullname | Where-Object {$_.Fullname -like 'COO'} | Export-Csv c:users\shay\desktop\test.csv
```

Comment: You need to use wildcards if you want folders with `COO` somewhere in their name returned. `-like '*COO*'`. Without wildcards, `-like` acts as `-eq` and if there is no folder called COO you won't find anything

Comment: In this case, you could also use `-match 'COO'` which will treat `COO` as a regex and will also work if it's just part of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `-Like` parameter you'll need to include a wildcard (*), try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory | select Fullname | where-object {$_.Fullname -like '*COO*'} | Export-csv c:users\shay\desktop\test.csv
```

You could also potentially move the expression to the `Get-ChildItem` portion of this snippet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory -Filter '*COO*' | select Fullname | Export-csv c:users\shay\desktop\test.csv
```